# Set Expiration on end of the day

Tags: javascript, date, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie that will expire at the end of the day. I've create this function :

```
function mnc(cname,cvalue)
{
    var now = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();

    expire.setFullYear(now.getFullYear());
    expire.setMonth(now.getMonth());
    expire.setDate(now.getDate()+1);
    expire.setHours(0);
    expire.setMinutes(0);

    //alert(expire.toGMTString() + " " + expire.toString());
    var expires = "expires="+expire.toString();
    alert(expires + "=> now =" + now);
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires +"; path=/";
}
```

On Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MYs6b/

So, the alert box show me the good expiration date. 
But, if I change the date on my computer by adding 1 or 100 days, i still have the same value in the cookie.

Why? I'm searching since 3 hours and i don't understand...

**EDIT :**

I've had an alert on "document.cookie" is empty

```
http://jsfiddle.net/MYs6b/2/
```

**EDIT 2 :**
I've add a better example of my problem. It's working on IE and FF but not on chrome :

```
http://jsfiddle.net/5h87M/1/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This: http://jsfiddle.net/MYs6b/1/

```
function mnc(cname,cvalue)
{
    var now = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();

    expire.setFullYear(now.getFullYear());
    expire.setMonth(now.getMonth());
    expire.setDate(now.getDate()+1);
    expire.setHours(0);
    expire.setMinutes(0);
    expire.setSeconds(0);

    var expires = "expires="+expire.toString();
    alert(expires + "=> now =" + now);
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires +"; path=/";
}

mnc("test", "123456");
```

Comment: I think thats because chrome - or maybe all the browsers are using server time, but thats just a speculation. So just for concistency, try changing the server time instead of client time.

Answer (score 1):

```
function createCookie(name,value,path) {
    var expires = "";
    var date = new Date();
    var midnight = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);
    expires = "; expires=" + midnight.toGMTString();

    if (!path) {
        path = "/";
    }

    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=" + path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Last update of chrome correcting this issue.